# Hibernate+SQLite+Netbeans

Tags: hibernate, sqlite, netbeans

Can someone please tell me where can I find the driver and the dialect files to connect hibernate to sqlite?

Answer (score 5):

Since SQLite database is widely used and it is not well supported by Hibernate(not NHibernate) in java,it's not easy to use SQLite with Hibernate.[This project is to help you quickly start with SQLite-Hibernate programming](http://code.google.com/p/hibernate-sqlite/)