# sqlite and hibernate - is good idea?

Tags: java, hibernate, sqlite

I am developing a small desktop application with Java + Hibernate. I am using MySQL for development but want to replace it with light version of SQL like SQLLite .
I want to do this for following reasons:

- To avoid installation and configuration of MySQL. This will allow my clients to install and configure the application on their own.
- To ease backup and restore of DB.
- etc.

I found SQLLiteDialect, its configurations and a working sample eclipse project(uses hibernate3) on http://code.google.com/p/hibernate-sqlite/.

But when I read the [comment on a question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3119866/607637)  :  "*Since SQLite database is widely used and it is not well supported by Hibernate in java,it's not easy to use SQLite with Hibernate*" I got frightened.

Can you please suggest me - is it a good idea to use SQLite here? 
Are there any alternative to SQLite that is well supported by Hibernate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there are pros and cons to every DB out there. For embedded DB's, you could also look at HSQLDB or H2DB.

Comment: HSQLDB or H2DB... interesting. are these well supported by Hibernate ?