# Does Hibernate Fully Support SQLite?

Tags: java, sqlite, hibernate, jpa

Jboss Hibernate doesn't say anything about the support for SQLite in [its wiki](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/SupportedDatabases2).

And the same is mentioned in this Stack Overflow post: [Hibernate+SQLite+Netbeans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3119849/hibernatesqlitenetbeans/3119866#3119866)

Can you please highlight about this? I want to use embedded SQLite with Hibernate for a Swing desktop application.

I am also evaluating Derby (JavaDB) as it also can be embedded and is part of the JDK.

Comment: Have you looked at the H2 database? It's got a small footprint, is embeded and works well with Hiberna

Comment: Thanks Jason. I just did a quick comparison and H2 looks interesting. I will discuss it with my team.

Comment: A very mature and stable, 100% Java RDBMS is available in HSQLDB which has been developed going on 20 years.  The database and JDBC 4+ driver can be downloaded at http://www.hsqldb.org.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Since SQLite is an embedded database for C-like environments, written in C and thus compiled to native code, changes that Hibernate (or any ORM) will support aren't really high. Java is cross-platform and it would be a bit weird to have a platform-dependent dependency. On Android, SQLite is used, but there the platform supplies a JDBC driver for it.

Usually, Windows binaries are compatible over different Windows versions - as long as the architecture stays the same. If you look at the [SQLite download page](http://www.sqlite.org/download.html) you'll notice there's a 32-bit pre-built Windows binary. This one can be used on almost any Windows version (except Windows RT, maybe), but you cannot use it on Linux or OS X. In order to use SQLite from Java, you would need to include the correct binary for the specific OS / architecture, effectively making a Java application platform-dependent. That is something you usually don't want.

If you're building a desktop application in Swing and you want to use an embedded database, my suggestion would be to use a Java embedded database, like [H2](http://www.h2database.com), [HSQL](http://www.hsqldb.org) or [Derby](http://db.apache.org/derby). The latter is also shipped with Oracle Java as [JavaDB](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javadb/overview/index.html). All are supported as hibernate dialects (For a full list of dialects, see the dialect classes: https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/tree/master/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/dialect)

As noted below by @akostadinov, there may be other factors you want to consider, for example the fact that SQLite is written in native code and hence *may* have better performance. In the end, the only one who can decide which database is best is the one who is building the system.

Comment: I got your point for hibernate but for platform dependency sqlite documentation says - A database in SQLite is a single disk file. Furthermore, the file format is cross-platform. A database that is created on one machine can be copied and used on a different machine with a different architecture. SQLite databases are portable across 32-bit and 64-bit machines and between big-endian and little-endian architectures.

Comment: The database _file_ is portable over platforms - but the code to access such files is native code and thus needs to be compiled for every platform you want to run it on.

Comment: Then this means that even on different windows os - Vista, XP or 7, it will require separate compilation for supporting native code?

Comment: Yeah, but he may need also the performance and features provided by SQLite.

Comment: Consider [sqljet](http://sqljet.com/),SQLJet is an independent pure Java implementation of a popular SQLite database management system.

Comment: Going back to old question, why would hibernate care where or what the db is? As long as you provide the jdbc driver, it should work regardless of its sqlite or not, correct?

Comment: @excalibur that is correct. Supply your Hibernate-based application with a working SQLite driver and see for yourself :).

Comment: I also wanted to embed SQLite in my app, but I'm considering your suggestion... Does Hibernate fully support H2DB?

Comment: @Throoze, as far as I know, it should, but you can check the link in the OP.

Comment: If Android supports sqlite (probably through SNI), maybe compiling the C code into java bytecode would maybe solve the problem.

Comment: I appreciate the knowledge shown on cross-platform stuff, but this doesn't answer the question

Comment: SQLite is not limited to "C-like environments", code written in C can be compiled for many platforms. SQLite is available on windows, mac, linux and many processor architectures. SQLite can be use with Hibernate by using appropriate dialect and properly configured DataSource and good SQLite JDBC driver (https://github.com/xerial/sqlite-jdbc).

Comment: The platform independency argument is not very good since Hibernate does support some non platform-independent DBs like MS SQL (which is even mentioned 3rd on the list of supported databases)

Comment: The Xerial driver for SQLite (linked above) is cross-platform to any major platform you might reasonably deploy Java apps to. Yes, internally it uses native code, but it includes builds of that for all the supported platforms and knows how to pick the right version.

Comment: You may want to use the class org.hibernate.community.dialect.SQLiteDialect from the org.hibernate.orm:hibernate-community-dialects artifact on gradle / maven as discussed here https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/discussions/3783

Answer (score 60):

There are several SQLite dialects out there.

#### Hibernate 3:

https://github.com/kemitix/sqlite-dialect

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.kemitix</groupId>
    <artifactId>sqlite-dialect</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Hibernate configuration:

```
hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.SQLiteDialect
```

#### Hibernate 4:

https://github.com/EnigmaBridge/hibernate4-sqlite-dialect

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.enigmabridge</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate4-sqlite-dialect</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Hibernate configuration:

```
hibernate.dialect = com.enigmabridge.hibernate.dialect.SQLiteDialect
```

Note: I am author of this repository. Based on the `gwenn` repo.

#### Hibernate 5:

https://github.com/gwenn/sqlite-dialect/

Author worked with Hibernate team to integrate it to the Hibernate directly. It is tracked in this [issue](https://github.com/gwenn/sqlite-dialect/issues/7).

Add this dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.gwenn</groupId>
        <artifactId>sqlite-dialect</artifactId>
        <version>0.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

Hibernate configuration:

```
hibernate.dialect = org.sqlite.hibernate.dialect.SQLiteDialect
```

Comment: Using the jitpack.io solution for Hibernate 5, I found the property needed to be this: `hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.identity.SQLiteDialect` but it still didn't work. I got an exception with this message:

org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.spi.StrategySelectionException: Unable to resolve name [org.hibernate.dialect.identity.SQLiteDialect] as strategy [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect]

This was with Hibernate 5.0.12.

Comment: The Hibernate 5 version has been released to maven and the following can be found here: https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.github.gwenn/sqlite-dialect/0.1.0/jar

Comment: [The latest code for Hibernate 5](https://github.com/gwenn/sqlite-dialect/blob/master/src/main/java/org/sqlite/hibernate/dialect/SQLiteDialect.java) has a different classname than the answer.

The dialect should be: `org.sqlite.hibernate.dialect.SQLiteDialect`

Comment: Update for hibernate 6?

Comment: For version 6, use https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate.orm/hibernate-community-dialects.

Answer (score 7):

If you need to use SQLite with Hibernate for whatever reason then you need a custom dialect. It looks like there are a couple of implementations kicking around on the web.

I tried this one: https://github.com/gwenn/sqlite-dialect which worked for me with Hibernate 3 (I believe that it needs some updates for Hibernate 4). Note that you'll have to compile the code yourself and then set the `hibernate.dialect` configuration property to be `org.hibernate.dialect.SQLiteDialect`.

Other implementations that I found: http://code.google.com/p/hibernate-sqlite/ and https://gist.github.com/virasak/54436.

Answer (score 7):

From **Hibernate 6**, SQLite is part of the [community dialects in the Hibernate repository](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/main/hibernate-community-dialects/src/main/java/org/hibernate/community/dialect/SQLiteDialect.java).

Add the following dependency:

Gradle:

```kotlin
implementation("org.hibernate.orm:hibernate-community-dialects:6.4.1.Final")
```

Maven:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate.orm</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-community-dialects</artifactId>
    <version>6.4.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Set the dialect in one of your configuration files:

JPA (`src/main/resources/META-INF/persistence.xml`):

```xml
<persistence ...>
  <persistence-unit ...>
    <properties ...>
      <property name="jakarta.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.sqlite.JDBC"/>
```

Hibernate (`hibernate.properties`):

```
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.community.dialect.SQLiteDialect
```

Spring Boot (`application.properties`):

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.community.dialect.SQLiteDialect
```

Read more about Hibernate community-maintained dialects in [this Hibernate GitHub discussion](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/discussions/3783).

Comment: My gosh, you saved me more than 6 hours of digging... Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

SQLite is very forgiving about SQL syntax as far as I have experience with so it may work. I have not used SQLite extensively with hibernate but tried to use it with infinispan with some success. The stock SQLite jdbc driver that I found as the best recommended, lacks some of JDBC standard's methods so I had to patch it to have it working.

I think that you can try it with hibernate and see if it works. It may help you to see what I did to have it working with infinispan:
https://issues.jboss.org/browse/ISPN-2980

I know this is not the exact answer you would like to see but I decided to answer because I think there is little chance anybody else to answer in a more helpful way. At least when I was searching for more information at the time I couldn't find.