# SQLite Dynamic DB generation and Data population using JPA and Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, sqlite, spring-mvc, jpa

Development environment:

- Spring
- Hibernate
- JPA
- MySQL
- SQLite

Want to achieve following:

1. Fetch the data from Production DB i.e. MySQL.
   I am able to achieve this using JPA and Hibernate.
2. Dynamically generate the SQLite schema as per need and populate the data fetched from MySQL in step 1.

**Question:**
Is this possible to dynamically generate SQLite DB schema and populate data using JPA and Hibernate ? 
          If yes, how to do this?
          If no, which ORM to use to achieve this goal.

Other information:
I am using Spring tool suite, JPA and hibernate to implement persistence layer. I do not want to now go back and user standard SQL queries to dynamically create schema and populate data.

I goggled around and did not get any help for this.
I also looked at the Hibernate(ORM implementation) but do not see any dedicated support for SQLite. Similar in SQLite official site.

Let me know if more detail is needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can create the DB Schema automatically with

```
 <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create" />
```

in your persistence.xml

your second question is answered here:
[Does Hibernate Fully Support SQLite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17587753/does-hibernate-fully-support-sqlite)
https://code.google.com/p/hibernate-sqlite/