# Easiest Way to Use Database in Sample Java Project?

Tags: java, database, maven, sample

I'll preface this with: I have very little database experience. I understand the concept of a database and how to use a database within Java, but I have no idea how to create one and my knowledge of SQL is essentially zilch.

I am creating a sample project to show off the features of IntelliJ to my company, in the hopes they will convert from Eclipse. One of the big features for our company will be database integration, so I would like to show off the Database tools. To do this, I need a database in the project. It doesn't need to be big or fancy or proper... it just needs to *be there*. It will never scale up. It will never be more than 10 rows and 4 or 5 columns.

Here's my requirements though:

- It needs to be *easy* to start the instance via Maven
- It can't be Derby (no Derby drivers in our Maven repo)
- It must work with Hibernate and Spring
- Everything must run through Maven - no IDE specific stuff
- The database content needs to be persistent so I can push it to the project repository (as in, not an in-memory DB that is deleted as soon as the connection closes)

How can I create this? How do I create the file with the DB content? How do I start the instance via Maven? If it is something like HSQLite and the DB content is stored in a *.sql file, how do I do I automate starting an instance and running the file with a single maven command?

The key here is easy. I want a dummy (like me) with no idea how to do this to be able to run this project and try it for him or herself.

Thanks for any help that's out there!

David

Comment: It seems weird that you want to create a database driven application, but you want to skip learning the basics about databases. You're going to have to learn *something* if you want to achieve your goal. Why not just look for a database tutorial?

Comment: [This](http://m.wikihow.com/Create-a-Database-in-MySQL) looks about as simple as it gets. It's a MySQL tutorial. MySQL would be my first choice for a database if I was you.

Comment: Two reasons I'd like to get around learning DBs right now: 1) I'm not getting paid for this; 2) I far more interesting projects to work on at home than learning DBs. **But**, with that said, thank you for the tutorial link. I'll check that out first thing tomorrow.

Comment: I bet learning good database fundamentals now will pay you back 1,000 times over if you have any kind of future as a programmer.

Comment: @jahroy, I just got a notif about this question which has me re-reading it. I'm having a good laugh at my response to your comment. Thank you for being gracious...
Yes, learning DBs certainly became an important part of my job over the last seven years!

And for anyone curious, it took more than three years after this question was posed before IntelliJ Ultimate was finally adopted, but I did get to see that change through!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try sqllite for a simple database that persists data to a file.  There is a jdbc driver for it here: https://bitbucket.org/xerial/sqlite-jdbc along with instructions for use. You can see that when you specify the connection, you pass in a file name.  The driver itself can be downloaded via maven.

It seems like there's some question as to whether you can use hibernate with it: [Does Hibernate Fully Support SQLite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17587753/does-hibernate-fully-support-sqlite). It seems like it might be worth a shot.

One step up in complexity is hsqldb. I often use it for testing hibernate persistence layers in memory (with the production app using mysql or oracle). So I know that it works with spring/hibernate: http://hsqldb.org/.

Have fun!

Comment: SQLite looks good and I've run into it a number of times. Can you give me super-dummy instructions for creating a database? Once I have the file created, I can connect to it via IntelliJ's GUI and add my sample contents.

Comment: The data file will be created as soon as you make the connection in your code:

Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:/home/leo/work/mydatabase.db");

Comment: Well... that was fun. It took some time and another thread to get it working, but it finally does work and it's beautifully simple. [Here](https://github.com/SwimDude0614/CrewCallerKata_Intellij) is the project and [here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23201073/how-to-integrate-sqlite-db-file-and-hibernate-when-controlled-by-spring/23201633) the other thread that helped me finally get it up and running.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need a database and don't necessarily have to create one using IntelliJ. I would write the database in SQL and then connect to it using IntelliJ. That's just my take on it cause you'd have to use external modules/packages if you wanted to create it through Java.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest h2 http://www.h2database.com/html/main.html
It's java, it can load sql, it will create a db file if you use file mode