# Easy to use database for java project

Tags: java, database

I am writing a little java application that will handle (potentially) a lot of data on the user's device. The structure of my data is this:

item type 1 contains

- integer variable
- png/jpeg image
- 2 string variables
- custom datatype containing two strings and a double
- list of other items of this type
- list of items of type 2 who contain this item

item type 2 contains

- string variable
- list of items of type 1

I have honestly no idea what I could use to store this data. It should just be easy to add it to the program without requiring too many additional installation steps for the user. What do you think is best?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22876460/easiest-way-to-use-database-in-sample-java-project

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Easiest Way to Use Database in Sample Java Project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22876460/easiest-way-to-use-database-in-sample-java-project)

Comment: How much data do you consider "a lot of data"? For a lot of data, I like PostgreSQL.

Comment: type 1 could be anything from 500 to 10000 items at the beginning and increasing over time. type 2 probably not more than 100. Can you include postrgreSQL in the project so that it is installed right with the app? Also, last time I used postgreSQL, my professor said we should shut it down after we are done because it's a security risk, so maybe not too suitable for an app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with `H2 Database`. Some of the features are:

- Very fast, open source, JDBC API
- Embedded and server modes; in-memory databases
- Browser based Console application
- Small footprint: around 2 MB jar file size
- Nice documentation and also the creator is active here on Stackoverflow ;-) and can help!

Look here for more: https://www.h2database.com/html/main.html

Comment: I'm trying this, but so far the tutorials I found all use the view/tool windows/database tool in intellij, which is only available in ultimate edition. Any way to get this done with just community?

Comment: You can use it with Intellij Community Edition with your java code, and view the data with H2 Console for example or any other database viewer that supports `JDBC` connection.

Answer (score 0):

For starter, you can use SQLite for simple database. But from your story, I think Google Guava suits your needs better.

https://github.com/google/guava/wiki

You may store the data to file before the app exits and load it to memory again when it runs.

Check this one for database-like memory 100% pure Java. http://hsqldb.org/

Answer (score -1):

you could use sqlite as it is a file-based database, it should work great without any installation (just add a library to your project to handle it). https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-java/
You should store the images in a folder though