# Embed database in spring project with hibernate

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-boot

In my previous spring projects, I always use hibernate+postgresql to store the data. I rencently start to use spring-boot, and I am looking for a database system which allow me embed it in my project, without be required the installation of a external DBMS.

I try use SQLite, but in my searches I found some afirmations Hibernate isn't compatible with SQLite.

Anyone knows if this is possible and could point me a solution?

Comment: Check out h2 or hsql, both embeddeable SQL databases with good spring support via the `EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We've successfuly used [HSQLDB](http://hsqldb.org/) with Hibernate for ages.

This is actually super cool for sales, you can demonstrate a working application on (potential) customers machine with the embedded HSQLDB database. And still be able to switch to "the real thing" later on.

See also this:

[Does Hibernate Fully Support SQLite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17587753/does-hibernate-fully-support-sqlite)

and this:

https://code.google.com/p/hibernate-sqlite/