# I try to save data with Hibernate and SQLite DB but have SQLException: NYI

Tags: java, hibernate, sqlite

When I try to update rows that already exists all is fine. Problem only with save method.
My map class looks like follow:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "person")
public class Person{

    @Transient
    private PropertyChangeSupport propertyChangeSupport = new PropertyChangeSupport(this);

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long personID = null;

    @Column
    private String firstName;

    @Column
    private String lastName;

    @Column
    private Gender gender;

    @Column(name = "birthday")
    private Date birthday;
    /*
    @Column
    @Temporal(value=TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date dateOfDeath;
    */
    @Column
    private String education;

    @Column
    private String profession;

    @Column
    private String city;

    @Column
    private String otherInfo;

    @Column(name ="firstParentID")
    private Long firstParentID;

    @Column(name = "secondParentID")
    private Long secondParentID;

    public Person(){
    }

    public Person(Long parentID){
        this.firstParentID = parentID;
    }

    public Long getPersonID() {
        return personID;
    }

    public void setPersonID(Long personID) {
        this.personID = personID;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        propertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange("firstName", this.firstName, this.firstName = firstName);
    }
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        propertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange("lastName", this.lastName, this.lastName = lastName);
    }

    public String getGender() {
        if (gender != null)
            return gender.getDescription();
        return null;
    }
    public void setGender(String genderType) {
        propertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange("gender", this.gender, this.gender = Gender.valueOf(genderType));
    }
    public Date getBirthday() {
        return birthday;
    }
    public void setBirthday(Date birthday) {
        propertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange("birthday", this.birthday, this.birthday = birthday);
    }
    /*
    public Date getDateOfDeath() {
        return dateOfDeath;
    }
    public void setDateOfDeath(Date dateOfDeath) {
        propertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange("dateOfDeath", this.dateOfDeath, this.dateOfDeath = dateOfDeath);
    }
    */
    public String getEducation() {
        return education;
    }
    public void setEducation(String education) {
        propertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange("education", this.education, this.education = education);
    }
    public String getProfession() {
        return profession;
    }
    public void setProfession(String profession) {
        propertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange("profession", this.profession, this.profession = profession);
    }
    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }
    public void setCity(String city) {
        propertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange("city", this.city, this.city = city);
    }
    public String getOtherInfo() {
        return otherInfo;
    }
    public void setOtherInfo(String otherInfo) {
        propertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange("otherInfo", this.otherInfo, this.otherInfo = otherInfo);
    }
    public long getFirstParentID() {
        return firstParentID;
    }
    public void setFirstParentID(Long firstParentID) {
        propertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange("firstParentID", this.firstParentID, this.firstParentID = firstParentID);
    }
    public long getSecondParentID() {
        return secondParentID;
    }
    public void setSecondParentID(Long secondParentID) {
        propertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange("secondParentID", this.secondParentID, this.secondParentID = secondParentID);
    }

     public void addPropertyChangeListener(String propertyName, PropertyChangeListener listener) {
         propertyChangeSupport.addPropertyChangeListener(propertyName, listener);
     }

     public void removePropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener listener) {
         propertyChangeSupport.removePropertyChangeListener(listener);
     }

}
```

I try to save Person with null personID by following method:

```
@Override
    public void savePerson(Person p) {
        Session session = null;
        try{
            session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
            session.beginTransaction();
            session.save(p);
            session.getTransaction().commit();
        }finally{
            if (session != null && session.isOpen())
                session.close();
        }
    }
```

But I have SQLException and GenericJDBCException: Could not prepare statement. I'll skip the details and describe only important:

```
    ...
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not prepare statement
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:54)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:196)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:122)
    at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractSelectingDelegate.performInsert(AbstractSelectingDelegate.java:55)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3032)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3558)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:98)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:492)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addResolvedEntityInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:197)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:181)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addAction(ActionQueue.java:216)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.addInsertAction(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:334)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:289)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:195)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:209)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:55)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:194)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:49)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:90)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSave(SessionImpl.java:715)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:707)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:702)
    at db.DAO.impl.PersonDAOImpl.savePerson(PersonDAOImpl.java:21)
...
    Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: NYI
    at org.sqlite.Conn.prepareStatement(Conn.java:217)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$2.doPrepare(StatementPreparerImpl.java:124)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:186)
    ... 61 more
```

hibernate.cfg.xml:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
                                             "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
    <hibernate-configuration>
     <session-factory name="">
      <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.sqlite.JDBC</property>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:sqlite:C:\\TEST\MyDB</property>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.autocommit">false</property>
      <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
      <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect</property>
      <mapping class="people.Person"/>
     </session-factory>
    </hibernate-configuration>
```

Comment: Update the code for Gender class. How are you mapping it?

Comment: @PrerakTiwari Gender is enum. It's not mapping.

Comment: Which driver you are using? NYI Means "Not Yet Implemented". Your version of SQLite simply isn't completely implemented.

Comment: @PrerakTiwari I'm using Xerial driver:  sqlite-jdbc-3.8.11.1.jar

Answer (score 0):

`NYI means "Not Yet Implemented"`. There are multiple SQLite drivers out there. Make sure you use the [Xerial driver](https://bitbucket.org/xerial/sqlite-jdbc) and not the Zentus driver which does not support generated ids. Refer [this](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/doc-files/ormlite_2.html#index-SQLite-database) link.

Also, the **Dialect** which you used for SQLIte is **incorrect**. For More information Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17587753/does-hibernate-fully-support-sqlite) SO thread.

Comment: Oh, I fogot to say about it in post. I tried to solve this problem and I'm using Xerial driver.

Comment: can you share the hibernate configuration then?

Comment: I shared. Look at end of post.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using right Dialect..?
Configuration is showing HSQL and you are using SQL Lite.
Please check and reply if it works. You can check for some customized dialect as well.

Comment: You should not ask questions by posting answers. Please use comments instead