# Do I need to specify PostgreSQL dialect in Maven dependencies?

Tags: hibernate, postgresql, maven

I'm reading a friend course to have a better understanding of Maven. He is working with SQLite. He has these dependencies in Maven project :

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.xerial</groupId>
    <artifactId>sqlite-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.11.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.kemitix</groupId>
    <artifactId>sqlite-dialect</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

I'd like myself to work with PostgreSQL. So far I've added :

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
    <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
    <version>9.1-901-1.jdbc4</version>
</dependency>
```

But is there not a dependency related to the PostgreSQL dialect as I can see with SQLite? Or is it included in the PostgreSQL dependency above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems [`net.kemitix:sqlite-dialect`](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.kemitix/sqlite-dialect/0.1.0) is a dependency that is used for Hibernate:

> SQLite dialect for Hibernate

This is because [Hibernate does not support SQLite databases out of the box](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17587753/1743880): we need to explicitely add a dialect (that is, a way for Hibernate to communicate to and understand the database).

Fortunately for you, if you want to use PostgreSQL, Hibernate supports it and [there are already built-in PostgreSQL dialects](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/javadocs/org/hibernate/dialect/package-summary.html). Therefore, you don't need to add another dependency: the PostgreSQL driver is enough.