# Spring boot & Hibernate ORM use in android it is practical?

Tags: android, hibernate, spring-boot

I get to learn spring boot & hibernate object relation mapping(ORM) used in server-side.

Since Spring boot using JAVA, I like it provided library that able performing CRUD with just interface without need to code implementation of the query.

I know Spring boot this framework is not mean for mobile, but may I know will it too overkill if implement in modern android phone for data manipulation?
Average phone will run fine?

Thanks.

Comment: I would say it is an overkill to use an ORM like Hibernate, with tons of functions in Android. Not because of having tons of functions, but also becase of having lots of transitive dependencies and it might be a problem to [use it with Sqlite too](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17587753/does-hibernate-fully-support-sqlite). There are many Android specific ORMs, you would rather go with one of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want to use ORM, I recommend using [ORMLite for Android](http://ormlite.com/).

Like @Xtreme Biker mentioned, Hibernate is way too overkill for Android apps. However, you could opt to use ORMLite as it basically works almost in the same principle as Hibernate. You can also use Javax Persistence annotations like `@Id`, `@Column`, `@OneToOne`, etc. as well.

Read the documentation [here](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/doc-files/ormlite_2.html#Javax-Persistence-Annotations).