# Problems with dialect SQLite 3 with Hibernate 5

Tags: java, hibernate, sqlite, maven, jpa

I'm facing some problems with Hibernate-JPA-Maven

It's the first time I use JPA and hibernate and I have some problems :
I have a database that I have created with JPA and I would like to make some CRUD tests on it with JUnit5.
With the pom.xml I add dependency to work with a SQLite dialect and hibernate, and I have a persistence.xml file.
I use Eclipse to run the project to see if the first simple test works and i have this problem :

> oct. 28, 2017 2:42:32 PM org.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper
>   logPersistenceUnitInformation INFO: HHH000204: Processing
>   PersistenceUnitInfo [     name: Bla   ...] oct. 28, 2017 2:42:32 PM
>   org.hibernate.Version logVersion INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core
>   {5.2.12.Final} oct. 28, 2017 2:42:32 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment
>    INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found oct. 28, 2017
>   2:42:32 PM
>   org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager
>    INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations
>   {5.0.1.Final} oct. 28, 2017 2:42:33 PM
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl
>   configure WARN: HHH10001002: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool
>   (not for production use!) oct. 28, 2017 2:42:33 PM
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl
>   buildCreator INFO: HHH10001005: using driver [org.sqlite.JDBC] at URL
>   [jdbc:sqlite::memory:] oct. 28, 2017 2:42:33 PM
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl
>   buildCreator INFO: HHH10001001: Connection properties: {charSet=UTF-8,
>   password=****, user=test} oct. 28, 2017 2:42:33 PM
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl
>   buildCreator INFO: HHH10001003: Autocommit mode: false oct. 28, 2017
>   2:42:33 PM
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections
>    INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 20 (min=1)
>   oct. 28, 2017 2:42:33 PM
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator
>   initiateService WARN: HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query
>   metadata : Unable to determine Dialect to use [name=SQLite,
>   majorVersion=3]; user must register resolver or explicitly set
>   'hibernate.dialect' Exception in thread "main"
>   org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested
>   service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]   at  . . .
>   Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Access to
>   DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set
>     at  . . .   ... 14 more

So I have i try to find out why I have :

> WARN: HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata :
>   Unable to determine Dialect to use [name=SQLite, majorVersion=3]; user
>   must register resolver or explicitly set 'hibernate.dialect'

Apparently this is because SQLite 3 and Hibernate 5 are not compatible, so I try this : [Does Hibernate Fully Support SQLite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17587753/does-hibernate-fully-support-sqlite) but it was not working for me.

Then I try to take a lower version of hibernate and modify in my pom.xml the hibernate version and hibernate-core versions to 4.3.11.Final but same, it doesn't solved my problems.

After many hours on that, I can't figure it out if the problems comes from the version of hibernate and SQLite, or if this is a problem of the configuration in my pom.xml (a missing dependency ?) or it's my persistance.xml, or this comes from my class Test.

[File tree of my project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4YWWF.png)

Please let me know if you need more details.
Thank you in advance for your help.

My pom.xml file :

```
<project
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>fr.umlv.orthopro</groupId>
  <artifactId>OrthoPro_brain</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>OrthoPro_brain</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
     <java.version>9</java.version>
     <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
     <junit.jupiter.version>5.0.1</junit.jupiter.version>
     <junit.platform.version>1.0.1</junit.platform.version>
     <hibernate.version>5.2.12.Final</hibernate.version>
     <sqlite.version>3.20.1</sqlite.version>
  </properties>

  <build>
     <plugins>
         <plugin>
             <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
             <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
             <version>3.7.0</version>
             <configuration>
                 <source>${java.version}</source>
                 <target>${java.version}</target>
                 <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                 <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
             </configuration>
         </plugin>
         <plugin>
             <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
             <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
             <version>3.0.0-M1</version>
             <configuration>
                 <reportOutputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/javadoc</reportOutputDirectory>
                 <destDir>javadoc</destDir>
                 <nohelp>true</nohelp>
             </configuration>
         </plugin>
     </plugins>
  </build>
  <dependencies>
     <dependency>
         <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
         <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
         <version>${junit.jupiter.version}</version>
         <scope>test</scope>
     </dependency>
     <dependency>
         <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
         <artifactId>junit-platform-runner</artifactId>
         <version>${junit.platform.version}</version>
         <scope>test</scope>
     </dependency>
     <dependency>
         <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
         <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
         <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
     </dependency>
     <dependency>
         <groupId>org.xerial</groupId>
         <artifactId>sqlite-jdbc</artifactId>
         <version>${sqlite.version}</version>
         <!-- <scope>test</scope> -->
     </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.12.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>
 </project>
```

My persistence.xml file :

```xml
 <persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
                 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                 xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence
                 http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd"
                 version="2.1">

        <persistence-unit name="first_test" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
          <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
           <class>fr.umlv.orthpro.db.User</class>
           <class>fr.umlv.orthpro.db.Rule</class>
           <class>fr.umlv.orthpro.db.UserRule</class>
           <class>fr.umlv.orthpro.db.Sentence</class>

            <properties>
                <property name="dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.SQLiteDialect" />
                <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.sqlite.JDBC" />
                <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:sqlite::memory:" />
                <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="test" />
                <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="test" />
                <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
                <property name="format_sql" value="true" />
                <property name="hibernate.connection.charSet" value="UTF-8" />
                <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create" />
            </properties>
        </persistence-unit>
    </persistence>
```

This is my class to run test on the database :

```
package fr.umlv.orthopro.db;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;

public class Test {
      EntityManagerFactory emfactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory( "first_test" );

      EntityManager entitymanager = emfactory.createEntityManager( );
      entitymanager.getTransaction( ).begin( );

      User quentin = new User( ); 
      quentin.setId(1201);
      quentin.setAdmin(false);

      entitymanager.persist( quentin );
      entitymanager.getTransaction( ).commit( );
      entitymanager.close( );
      emfactory.close( );
    }
}
```

EDIT : I change
`<property name="dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.SQLiteDialect" />` to
`<property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.SQLiteDialect" />`
and now I have this :

> Unable to resolve name [org.hibernate.dialect.SQLiteDialect] as
>   strategy [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect]

Comment: few lightweight Db have better opinion: H2, Derby aka JavaDB, HSQLDB with JPA

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have the choice of the framework and the DB, I have to use SQLite, but i'm aware that there is more efficient and easier DB to use with JPA

Comment: Just to clarify: you have a `dialect` property in your persistence.xml. It should be `hibernate.dialect`, is that a typo?

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking that it was actually `dialect` instead of `hibernate.dialect` ! Now I have : `Could not obtain connection to query metadata : Unable to resolve name [org.hibernate.dialect.SQLiteDialect] as strategy [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect]`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I am using SQLite 3.10 with Hibernate 5.2 with the following configuration:

pom.xml:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.12.Final</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.xerial/sqlite-jdbc -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.xerial</groupId>
    <artifactId>sqlite-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>3.20.1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.zsoltfabok/sqlite-dialect -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.zsoltfabok</groupId>
    <artifactId>sqlite-dialect</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

persistence.xml:

```
<persistence version="2.1"
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">

    <persistence-unit name="first_test" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class" />
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.SQLiteDialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="org.sqlite.JDBC" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.user" value="" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.autocommit" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:sqlite:sqlite.db"/>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.flushMode" value="ALWAYS" />
            <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" value="false" />
            <property name="hibernate.cache.provider_class" value="org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider" />

            <!-- create https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/manual/en-US/html/ch03.html -->
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="validate or create" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

Of course you have to change the value of `hibernate.connection.url` and `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` and maybe other properties to your needs.